# i need the div to got to the left when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I have a graph that looks like this (yes it needs some styling ): 
[whole graphic when window is larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnJzd.png)

this is a graphic seen in its entirety.
When i make the window smaller, it cuts of the right side of the graphic. I don't want that i want the grapihc to go left to show the right side of the graph when its smaller. does anyone know how to do this?

[this happens when resizing windows to mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wvLy.png)

[i need it to do this. entire graphic to go to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ8Hk.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the link you have provided, the graph resizes. But if you want to show your right side of the graph, fix the width and then use position property along with right: (any)px.

Hope this is what you were talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a demo below. Where .graph is your graph.
Add `absolute position` with `0 right` with `100% width and height`.

By default I have set **100% width** to the graph.

For smaller screens, specify the proper dimensions in `media query` and fix the width of graph. Thus it would stick to the right once the screen width exceeds your graph width.

```css
.graphCont{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.graph{
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background: orange;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
 .graph{
    width:300px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="graphCont">
  <div class="graph">
  </div>
</div>
```